# how to capture user activity using javascript or angular

Tags: javascript, angular

i have an assignment to create a chatbot plugin using angular and the app can be imported to other website framework.

there is an objective that i need to get the user activity on the page (not on the chatbot plugin), something like if the user click/hover any specific tag such as `a` tag or `img` tag, that tag will send to the server

imagine website owner have this code in their site

```
<a class="view-products" target="_self" href="https://alfaprav.com/shop/"><span>Shop More</span></a>
```

when the user click/hover that tag it will send to the server as a string

i've followed several stackoverflow solutions but didn't suits my need. this is the closest solution  http://jsfiddle.net/94dd343y/ but i dont know how to implement that to my app, is it needs to be inserted inside my angular app or i need new `.js` file just for that. any thought would be very helpful

EDIT

here's how this plugin will look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kavVz.png)

EDIT 2

Thanks to [Julian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10125418/julian-liu) now i have this code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      // console.log(e.target);
      console.log(e.target);
      
    }, false);
    }
```

and i got the tags, but there's problem when user click body it shows all tags from  to  how to prevent that?

EDIT 3

After reading answer from [pooya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/915693/pooya-estakhri) i change it to this

```
const elements = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('div');
elements.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', (e =>{
    console.log(e.target);
  }))
})
```

Comment: Is it an AngularJS or an Angular 2+ project?

Comment: its angular 2+ project, im using latest angular version

Comment: Have you tried `document.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log('type: %s, target: %s', e.type, e.target), false);`?

Comment: alli can think of is doing the tracking thing using jquery outside my apps, do you think its possible if im doing this on angular component?

Comment: should i added that to the component.ts? nothing seems happening

Comment: i've tried using jquery,its working now i can get `e.srcElement` but i want this to be a string, but if i add `.toString()` it says its not a function

Comment: and also, how to exclude `body` tag from firing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add event Listener to tags you intend to follow:

```
  <body>
    <a href="https://google.com/">google</a>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zT36YJ3.jpg" />
    <script>
      const aTags = document.querySelectorAll("a");
      const imgTags = document.querySelectorAll("img");

      aTags.forEach((aTag) => {
        aTag.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
          console.log(e.target);
        });
        aTag.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
          console.log(e.target);
        });
      });
      imgTags.forEach((imgTag) => {
        imgTag.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
          console.log(e.target);
        });
        imgTag.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
          console.log(e.target);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

This is just an example of how things can be done, you can send data to server instead of console logging them the solution definitely can be optimized based on specific needs.

I also suggest to send the data using [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) method to avoid interrupting smooth transition to different pages.

PS: i assume this is an assignment but in case of real world usage you should also take user privacy into account and be clear about it with bot users and also directly or indirectly with end users.

EDIT By Naoval

here's how to implement in typescript

add `public element: ElementRef` to `constructor` then u can use this code

```
const div = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('div');
const button = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button');
const img = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('img');
const a = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
div.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', (e => {
    console.log(e.target.outerHTML);
  }))
})
button.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', (e => {
    console.log(e.target.outerHTML);
  }))
})
img.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', (e => {
    console.log(e.target.outerHTML);
  }))
})
a.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', (e => {
    console.log(e.target.outerHTML);
  }))
})
```

Comment: how to use that on ts? currently answer from julian liu is fine, but i want to be more specific, cause rn it fires every tag on my site

Comment: ts? you mean type script ?

this code wont run on every element only a and img tags

Comment: i've edited my question, does what i'm doing is correct? and whats not secure about it?

Comment: @naovalluthfi i have no experience with angular so i can not comment on your changes.

my concerns were privacy wise not security wise, well it's sneaky if you capture user behavior unrelated to your service on a website  and send it to your server without notifying the website owner.

Comment: i see, thought you were talking about security. i just told to catch user action to show personalized message